# Input field value showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, forms, setinterval

I have an application that tests people on their times tables.  The sum is presented to the user and then they have to enter their answer into the input field.

The majority of this works but the value of the input field shows as `undefined` rather than the value that the user enters.

```js
let timesTableNumber = 2;
let listOfTables = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
let spellingItems = listOfTables.length;
let spellingItemShown = 0;
let checks = 0;
let answers = {
    rightAnswers: 0,
    wrongAnswers: [],
    numberOfSpellings:spellingItems,
    spellingGroup: "{{spelling.group}}",
    spellingId: "{{spelling._id}}",
    spellingcreatedBy: "{{spelling.createdBy}}",
    user: "{{user._id}}"
};

var checkSpellings = setInterval(function() {
    if (spellingItemShown > checks) {
      checkAnswer();
    }
    
    if (spellingItemShown < spellingItems){
        
        document.getElementById('spellings').innerHTML = timesTableNumber + 'x' + listOfTables[spellingItemShown]; 
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = timesTableNumber * listOfTables[spellingItemShown]; 

        //hide the spelling to be tested for x seconds
        var hideSpellings = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById('spellings').style.visibility  = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('form').style.removeProperty( 'visibility' );  
            document.getElementById('spelling').focus();  
            clearInterval(hideSpellings);            
        }, 3000);
        
        document.getElementById('spellings').style.removeProperty( 'visibility' );
        document.getElementById('form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                

    spellingItemShown ++;
    
    } else{
        //We're done!
        console.log('there were '+ answers.rightAnswers + ' right answers and the wrong answers were '+ answers.wrongAnswers);

        //post to server desired info....
   // axios.post('/spellings', answers);
    //showResults();

        console.log(answers);
        clearInterval(checkSpellings);
    }
}, 7000);

function checkAnswer(){
  console.log('checkAnswer:');
var correctAns =  timesTableNumber * listOfTables[spellingItemShown];
var userAns = document.getElementById('spelling').value;

  console.log('correctAns', correctAns);
  console.log('userAns', userAns);
  // debugger;
  if (userAns == correctAns){
    console.log('FOOOOOO');
    answers.rightAnswers ++;
  } else {

    console.log('yo');
    answers.wrongAnswers.push(document.getElementById('spellings').innerHTML);

  }
  document.getElementById("spelling").value = "";
  checks++
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">

<div id="spellingTest">
    <h2 id="spellings"></h2>
    <p id="answer" class="answer" style="visibility:hidden"></p>
<div id="form" class="spellings" style="visibility:hidden">
    <label for="spelling"> attempt</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="spelling" name="spelling"> 
</div>


<h3 id="spellingResults">Your results will show below at the end of the test.</h3>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Edit - I have resolved the `undefined` issue by changing the value of `userAns` to `var userAns = document.getElementById('spelling').value;` However there is now the issue that the correct answer is always one ahead of the actual correct answer e.g. correct answer for 2x2 shows as 6 rather than 4 and 3x2 shows as 8 rather than 6

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, it always logs the input value that I entered, never `undefined`. Your code logic needs fixing though. 2x2=4, but the log says the correct answer is 6. Also, the last question's answer is logged as `NaN`.

Comment: @JosephWebber thanks for looking at this.  I've been working on the issue and noticed a stupid mistake with how I was deriving the correct answer.  However as you say the logic is not right as the the answer is always one iteration ahead of where it should be